# JAVA : SWING : How can i build a .exe for Swing application

Tags: java, swing, deployment, exe, desktop-integration

I am trying to make a .exe file for a Swing Application by using InstallJammer.

I got the installation  file (project.exe) and installed.  After installation I could not find any icon to start the project.

How can I start this project after installation?

Any other ideas?

EDIT: How can i include my database ?

Comment: Why don't you use netbeans, it is easier.

Comment: is it possible in netbeans ? Can u provide some tutorial @NabeelOmer

Comment: Ok.....going to try that.........

Comment: https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … icon to start the project. … Any other ideas?

The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> … JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, **desktop integration,** file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Desktop integration is things like an icon on the desktop or menu items (in the start menu) to start the app.  Each with customized icons.

At least on supported systems, AFAIU OS X will not allow any desktop icons to clutter the user interface and *nix machines typically do not support the menu items (or didn't last time I checked).